# Android HTTPS Request?

Tags: java, android, https, request

I need to do a HTTPS request to access some data of the FB API. Actually I do a HTTP request with this lib http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
But this won't work for HTTPS.

Can anyone help me how to do a HTTPS request in Java with Android?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same classes you would for HTTP, but with an https prefix on the url.  The built in classes in Android like DefaultHttpClient and URLConnection work with https.